# Porque utilizar Redux para fazer requisições para API no React?

Tags: react, react-native, axios, redux, fetch

Comecei a ver React bem antes de aprender a utilizar Redux e sempre fazia as requisições na API utilizando um `Fetch` ou `Axios` no próprio componente.

Hoje já me aventuro no mundo do Redux e me deparo com pessoas realizando chamadas de API pelo Redux utilizando frameworks como `redux-saga` e `redux-thunk`, criando um código mais complexo, maior com vários reducers e actions para fazer uma requisição. Coisa que eu poderia fazer com apenas 4 ou 5 linhas utilizando `fetch` ou `axios`.

gostaria de saber se realmente se deve utilizar o Redux para realizar chamadas de API e o porquê devo utilizar para melhorar as minhas aplicações

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Danilo, geralmente eu uso o Redux quando preciso de usar uma resposta da consulta a API para mais de um componente e evitar o *props drill*. Quando os componentes estão totalmente separados então o Redux é uma excelente maneira de "compartilhar o estado" com os outros componentes. 
Recomendo uma leitura do blog da [Rocketseat](https://blog.rocketseat.com.br/redux-o-passo-a-passo/).

Comment: eu pensei nisso também, mas me deparei em uma situação que eu acho que não ia ficar muito legal com isso, por exemplo:

tenho uma listagem de componentes, nesses componentes tem um botão de favoritar o item, quando favoritar o item faz uma requisição para API informando que eu favoritei.

do jeito que eu faço eu coloco um setState no componente pra marcar que o item foi favoritado e só aquele componente ia atualizar. Se eu usar o redux pra isso, quando eu favoritasse, todos os itens da lista iam propagar essa mudança por causa do redux e eu teria que verificar se a mudança é para este item

Comment: Danilo, na verdade o Redux seria perfeito pra isso. Só os componentes que precisa ouviriam a alteração. Como a ideia do Redux é um estado global, apenas o item que você marcou como favorito ficaria assim. Eu uso o Redux com Saga numa aplicação aqui e funciona bem desse jeito mesmo.

Comment: Para entender os beneficios da store nas aplicações react, seria uma boa dar uma lida na [arquitetura Flux](https://facebook.github.io/flux/docs/overview.html#content) em português [Flux](https://tableless.com.br/flux-entenda-como-funciona-arquitetura-flux-com-react/)